# ASP.NET MVC IIS7.5: Error handling stopped working properly after moving website from W7 to Windows 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I use the following code in Global.asax.cs in order to log unhandled errors and transfer user to one of the error pages. Error pages are implemented as standard MVC controllers/views.

```
        protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();

        //Handle errors

        var httpException = ex as HttpException;
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
        routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
        routeData.Values["exception"] = ex;
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        if (httpException != null)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
            switch (Response.StatusCode)
            {
                case 403:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http403";
                    break;
                case 404:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
                    log.Error("Error 404 - User sees page not found page", ex);
                    break;
            }
        }
        log.Fatal("USER SEES ERROR 500 PAGE", ex);
        IController errorsController = new errorsController();
        var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
        errorsController.Execute(rc);
    }
```

It worked fine on the development machine (Windows 7 Pro). However, when I moved the site to Windows Server 2008 R2, the errors page stopped showing. Instead, I see standard IIS error pages. Yet, errors are logged properly.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Check to make sure the CustomErrors section in your web config file has not been jacked with.

Comment: Should I enable or disable custom errors for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have removed the `HandleErrorAttribute` global attribute registration from `Global.asax`. Or if you are using ASP.NET MVC 2 remove the `[HandleError]` attribute from your controllers. Also try setting `errorMode` to Detailed:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I removed it, but this behavior did not seem to change.

Comment: @AlexAvrutin, try setting `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />` in your web.config.

Comment: Thank you, it helped! What does this line change?